# Please merge this duplicate about old FIDE laws

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

[This](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27860/old-versions-of-fide-laws-of-chess) question about copies of old FIDE laws is a duplicate of [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/26807/fide-laws-of-chess-pre-2017) question, but it has high-quality and helpful answers that I think would be beneficial for the older question. Can the duplicate question please be merged into the older one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, it's merged now. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

[image]

It's fine to open a Meta question for these kind of unusual requests; another option is a custom ♦ moderator flag.